# database not update after install extension with composer in yii2 in SQLSRV connection

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

i used sqlsrv connection in yii2 and gii is worked correct!

this is my connection :

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=DESKTOP-UCQ1M4B;Database=shopping;ConnectionPooling=0',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
];
```

but when i want install extension in my Yii2 project extention has not error but database not update for example:
 i added this extention in project with this line:

```
composer require "dektrium/yii2-user:0.9.*@dev"
```

and this is return of composer :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-httpclient (2.0.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-authclient (2.1.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing dektrium/yii2-user (dev-master a908ab3)
    Cloning a908ab3652668c6f2755052098dac09a8c6de6f4 from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

but database not updated!!!

in mysql connection after install this extention database has update with create 3 table of users profile Structure!

Comment: What do you mean? Why you expect your database to be updated when you are adding package using composer?

Comment: in mysql after install this extention  database has update with create 3 table of users profile  Structure!

Comment: If i remember correctly  you should perform the related  migration  manually. Normally the migration are not performed  by composer ..